# axios or fetch get local json - strange response format and Unexpected token in JSON then i tried to parse it

Tags: json, vue.js, format, response

My axios response (or fetch, tried both) it's plain text (string). But I expect javaScript map. If I tried JSON.parse() (or from fetch .json()) I got error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at
> position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at eval (List.vue?8915:66)

- UTF-8 without BOM
- I checked my json via few json validators online - json is valid
- I tried create my json via some online json creator - the same error

so I have few questions:

1. I thought that json is a special format. If you got it via axios/fetch your response always will be js map? It's not true?
2. What is the best way to creating and validating json to be sure it's ok?
3. I use vue cli, there haven't json loader (i think so, not sure, it not use webpack, but I can't see some loaders). It could be problem? Or some environment settings? I tried to check it, but maybe can't find.
4. Or maybe ma header is still wrong, ad accept give me nothing?

votingService.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

export const getVotingsService = (): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    return axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/fakeData/votings.json", {
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
};
```

List.vue

```
...
  private getVotings() {
    getVotingsService().then(response => {
      console.log("resp", response.data); //string, data is ok
      console.log(JSON.parse(response.data)); //error
    });
  }
...
```

votings.json (in public folder)

```
{
    "votings": [
        {
            "createDate": "20-07-20",
            "deadline": "20-08-20",
            "status": "active",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        },
        {
            "createDate": "20-07-20",
            "deadline": "20-08-20",
            "status": "active",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        },
        {
            "createDate": "20-07-20",
            "deadline": "20-08-20",
            "status": "active",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        }
    ]
}
```

chrome consola:
[image]

chrome network response:
[image]

chrome network headers:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that response.data is a String and not directly converted into a javascript object ? Usually you get this type of error when you try to do JSON.parse(Object).
Maybe you just don't need to parse response.data then.

Comment: I'm sure that there isn't js obiect. I can't do something like response.data.votings because it's undefined. And I updated my main post to show what I have in chrome console. The first is without parsing (I got string) and second is then I tried parsing (error).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I'm not sure why, but VSCode didn't want to save me file without BOM, so I still had UTF-8 with BOM

Answer (score 0):

On August 20, 2020, Axios [released v0.20.0](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0200-august-20-2020) which addresses the issue of removing the byte order marker (UTF-8 BOM) when transforming the response.